# Data Access Layer returns DataTable

Tags: vb.net, design-patterns

Please have a look at the following question, which i asked some time ago: [Breaking BLL (Business Logic Layer) to BLL and DAL (Data Access Layer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112392/breaking-bll-business-logic-layer-to-bll-and-dal-data-access-layer)

This approach (Data Transfer Object) seems to work well if I am returning one record from the data access layer i.e. getNameByID returns one record.

What happens if you have a Data Access Layer function called getName(), which returns many records e.g. thousands or millions to be processed in the Business Logic Layer? (it is a scheduled task). When this is required I am currently returning a DataTable (because data readers cannot outlive a connection in VB.NET 2008).  However, this question and answer seems to negate this approach: [Is returning DataTable or DataSet from DAL is wrong approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705794/is-returning-datatable-or-dataset-from-dal-is-wrong-approach).  Is this a poor approach?

I realise there are ORM tools like NHibernate, which I plan to use more for future projects.  However, the data access code in my current project is already written by someone else but I want to refactor it as I go along.

Update
 Here is some code (as suggested by Stephen Doggart):

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

        Public Class PersonBLL
            Private Name As String
            Private Age As Integer

            Dim objPersonDAL As New PersonDAL
            Dim personList As List(Of Person)

            'Option 2
            Public Function getPersonByID() As List(Of Person)
                personList = objPersonDAL.getPersonByID()
                Return personList
            End Function



    Public Function ShowMessageBox(ByVal listPersonBLL As List(Of Person))
        For Each p As Person In listPersonBLL
            Me.Age = p.Age
            Me.Name = p.Name
            MsgBox(Me.Age)
            MsgBox(Me.Name)
        Next
    End Function

        End Class

        Public Class PersonDAL
            Private Name As String
            Private Age As Integer

            Public Function getPersonByID() As List(Of Person)
                'Connect to database and get Person.  Return a person object
                Dim personList As List(Of Person) = New List(Of Person)
                Dim p1 As New Person
                p1.Name = "Ian"
                p1.Age = 30
                personList.Add(p1)
                Dim p2 As New Person
                p2.Name = "Steven"
                p2.Age = 28
                personList.Add(p2)
                Dim p3 As New Person
                p3.Name = "Sharon"
                p3.Age = 29
                personList.Add(p3)
                Return (personList)
            End Function
        End Class

        Public Class Person
            Private _Name As String
            Private _Age As Integer

            Public Property Name() As String
                Get
                    Return _Name
                End Get
                Set(ByVal value As String)
                    _Name = value
                End Set
            End Property

            Public Property Age() As Integer
                Get
                    Return _Age
                End Get
                Set(ByVal value As Integer)
                    _Age = value
                End Set
            End Property
        End Class

    Public Class Form1

            Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
                'If Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(0) = "Test" Then
                'MsgBox("Test")
                'End If
                Dim p1 As PersonBLL = New PersonBLL
                Dim p2 As List(Of Person) = p1.getPersonByID()
                Dim p3 As PersonBLL = New PersonBLL
                p3.ShowMessageBox(p2)
            End Sub
        End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning a `DataTable` isn't completely terrible--there's certainly worse ways of doing it--it's only partly terrible.  But, who wants to eat partly terrible food unless they have no other option?

So, unless there's some reason why you need to use a `DataTable`, I would recommend sticking with custom DTO classes and just have your DAL return a list of those objects.  For instance:

```
Public Function GetNames() As List(Of NameDto)
    '...
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks.  +1 for the reference to List.  Do you follow the approach that you describe? Is your opinion any different if you have, say one million records to hold in the list?

Comment: Yes.  This is the approach I use, when possible.  A `List` object is pretty light-weight.  If anything, I'd assume it has less overhead than a `DataTable`.  I don't like the idea of returning millions of records at once, in any data type.  It would be better, in a case like that, if you could break it up in chunks or something, but if it works for your situation like that, without timing-out, I guess, why fix what isn't broken?

Comment: Thanks.  I was exaggerating when I said millions.  It is more like thousands.  Once the DTO object (List) is returned to the BLL, I will need to loop through it - do you populate the BLL classes's (PersonBLL) instance variables (Name and Age) on each loop or do you just use the values in the list and act on the values in the list?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean.  I guess I'd need to see an example of what you are talking about.

Comment: Please have another look at the original question.  I have posted some code.  Notice that I have added two options to the PersonBLL class (option 2 is commented out).  Are you able to answer the question in my last comment?

Comment: I would recommend option 2.  In that case, the business would also return a list of DTO's.  It's best, when possible, to keep everything outside the UI as stateless objects.  In other words the business and data access classes they contain methods, but not data.  The reason for this is because it makes it much easier in the future to separate the layers out into separate tiers, or to sandwich in an asynchronous layer, or to support multi-threading.  For all those reasons, it's best to keep data in dedicated DTO's and make all your logic classes be just logic with no state.

Comment: Thanks.  Last question.  I have amended the code to deal with passing Lists from the DAL.  Is this how you would deal with it? I wander what the point is initialising instance variables on every loop in the ShowMessageBox function?

Comment: Yes, except I wouldn't keep `personList` around as a field in `PersonBLL`.  The `getPersonByID` should just return it and be done with it.  Right now, it wouldn't work right if you called that method twice at the same time from two different threads.  (I suspect that was just a typo, though, and not the way you meant to do it.)

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify what you mean by a typo?

Comment: I'm saying, in the `PersonBll.getPersonByID` method, instead of putting `personList = objPersonDAL.getPersonByID()`, you'd just put `Return objPersonDAL.getPersonByID()`.  Since you aren't actually using the `personList` variable anywhere else, I assumed that perhaps that was just an accident.

Comment: Thanks.  In my last comment I was actually querying your comment about threading (I don't have much experience with multi threaded applcations).  I believe that you are saying that instance variables are not thread safe because they are stored on the heap.  I am developing a single threaded web app.  Therefore I do not believe there is a risk.  What steps would you take to make instance variables thread safe in a multi threaded app?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was referring to.  Instance variables do cause issues for multi-threading, which is why I was recommending that you don't have any, unless its really necessary.  To keep the instance variable and still make it thread-safe, you'd need to add a `SyncLock personList` block around each of the places in the code where you use that variable.  However, since, in your example, you aren't actually using that variable anywhere outside that method, I figured it wasn't really necessary and you could just get rid of it, which would be preferable.

Comment: this will be the last question.  Do you avoid using instance variables in multi threaded applications?

Comment: Yes, where possible.  Sometimes you need, or it just makes sense to have, an instance variable, and that's fine, but I think it's best to avoid them in your non-UI layers.

Comment: Please would you explain why the code in my question is not thread safe?

Comment: The method sets the `personList` field and then returns it.  So, if two threads were doing it at the same time, they might both set it first, before either of them return it.  In that case, which ever one was set last would win and that object same would be returned on both threads.  It would only be an issue if both threads were using the same instance of the PersonBLL class.

Comment: when you refer to Threads I assume you mean application threads created by the application rather than ASP.NET Worker threads?

Comment: Well, it doesn't really matter--a thread's a thread--but yes, that's generally what I had in mind when I brought it up.  With ASP.NET, I believe each thread would have it's own instance of the PersonBLL class, so it wouldn't be an issue.  I was just mentioning it in terms of best practices.  It's good to write the code in a way where it can be reused in any type of project.  So, if for instance, you ever needed to write a windows service which needed to use a PersonBLL object across multiple threads, it would be nice to not have to re-write the class :)

Comment: Could you answer the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485027/instance-variables-and-local-variables, so that I can give you some more credit?You have answered it with your last comment.

Comment: I have asked a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911041/listof-person-order.  Can you take a look if you have time?