# Should instance variables not be used since they cause mulithreading problems?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, coding-style

I understand that instance variables are not thread safe because they are stored on the heap.  I am refactoring code in an ASP.NET single threaded application and I am trying to use instance variables more.

My question is: do developers avoid using instance variables because of possible multi threading problems? (even if the app is not multi threaded now it may be in the future). I remember reading that instance variables should be used to improve design using composition and aggregation rather than association (as with local variables).

Is there any criteria that helps a developer to decide when to use instance variables and when to use local variables.  I have Googled this and I have looked on MSDN but I have not managed to find an answer to my specific question.

Comment: Can you give an example of code where you would lean towards using an instance variable?

Comment: @Steven Doggart, thanks for posting again.  It was your second to last comment to my last question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467167/data-access-layer-returns-datatable that has confused me.  I decided to create a new question as the conversation was moving away from the original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you done anything to make the ASP.NET application single threaded? Otherwise it's multi treaded by default.

Instance variables is only a problem with multi threaded applications if you share the object between threads. Normal for an ASP.NET application is that each thread creates its own instances of the objects, so the multi threading is not a problem.

If you need to share data between threads, encapsulating the data in an object is still the best approach. By using private instance variables and access them through methods or properties, you can make sure that all access from outside the object is synchronised, as the code in the object has full control over where the data is exposed.

Comment: +1.  I came accross this thread to suggest that multithreading can be a problem in ASP.NET: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benchr/archive/2008/09/03/does-asp-net-magically-handle-thread-safety-for-you.aspx

Comment: @w0051977: The article is pretty much correct in the conclusion about which types of access needs synchronising. As you see, most data that you normally use in an ASP.NET application doesn't need synchronisation.

Comment: Do instance variables need to be synchronised even if no threads are created in the code?

Comment: @w0051977: You only need to synchronise data that is reachable from more than one thread. That means either if you start new threads, or if you share data between threads that handle requests, for example by using static variables.

Comment: Thanks.  Are you saying that if I have an ASP.NET web app that calls web services and external DLLs but does not explicity create threads that there should not be a problem? Once I have your answer I will mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: @w0051977: Yes, as long as the code to handle a request doesn't specifically share data with other threads, it goes its own merry way, and threading is not a problem. Normally you don't have to think about it all. There are a lot of people building ASP.NET applciations who don't even know that IIS is multi threaded.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming are talking about web pages and instance variable of web page then you do not have to worry about the multi-threading and thread safety. The asp.net/web server will take care for that. This [**msdn article**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benchr/archive/2008/09/03/does-asp-net-magically-handle-thread-safety-for-you.aspx) discuss the thread safety provide by asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

You are in fact referring to **static** variables. Static variables are not thread-safe (in general, unless you write code to synchronize appropriate access to the variable). **Instance** variables, in contrast, *are thread-safe* in asp.net since each request thread will operate on its own copy.

**static** variables are meant to store data that needs to be shared among all requests. If you don't have such scenario, you shouldn't need to use static variables. And if you do, there are classes that already provide for this, such as the `Cache` class.

Comment: Thanks.  I am actually wandering if developers avoid using instance variables when they write code, which contains classes that contain Threads i.e. New Thread()

Comment: @w0051977 I still think you are confused about `static` and `instance` variables. If you provide sample code, I may be able to explain a bit better what are the risks of using static Vs instance variables in your code. In general, though, avoid using static variables in an asp.net app. You'll find that there's rarely need for them in a web app.

Comment: Thanks the answerer of my previous post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467167/data-access-layer-returns-datatable talked about limitations using Threading with instance variables (there is some code in the question).  Could you take a look?