# List(Of Person) ORDER

Tags: vb.net, design-patterns

Please take a look at the code below:

```
Public Class PersonTest

    Public Function ListTest()
        Dim list As List(Of Person) = New List(Of Person)
        Dim p1 As Person = New Person(1, "Ian")
        Dim p2 As Person = New Person(2, "Steven")
        Dim p3 As Person = New Person(3, "Sharon")
        list.Add(p1)
        list.Add(p2)
        list.Add(p3)
        For Each p As Person In list
            MsgBox(p.IDNumber)
        Next

    End Function

End Class

Public Class Person
    Public IDNumber As Integer
    Public Name As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal id As Integer, ByVal name As String)
        IDNumber = id
        name = name
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim pt As PersonTest = New PersonTest
        pt.ListTest()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I expect the Message Box to print: 1,2,3 which it does.  Can you confirm that List uses insertion order.  I am planning to store the results of database queries in a list i.e:

SELECT * FROM Person ORDER BY ID

The SQL statement is ordered by ID.  Can I assume that the List will also be ordered by ID?

The reason I ask is because the answerer to my question here: [Data Access Layer returns DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467167/data-access-layer-returns-datatable), suggests using a List to return an object from a Data Access Layer.

Comment: The list is not sorted on the "IDNumber", just in the order that you add it to the list.

Comment: The SQL statement below the code states that they will be entered into the list ordered by ID number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a list will store your objects as entered. See [List(Of T).Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1.aspx):

> Adds an object to the end of the List(Of T).

Comment: Thanks.  +1 for the reference.

Answer (score 2):

You can assume that [an `IList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx) will behave in this manner, yes.  Above just enumeration it also provides indexing so the sort of the list would need to remain constant to support that.

However, if you want to be explicit, you can always sort it explicitly:

```
For Each p As Person In list.OrderBy(Function(pe) pe.IDNumber)
```

Comment: Thanks +1 for the explicit override.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use a `SortedList`, which internally maintains its order based on the specified keys and the default comparer (unless you provide your own comparer).

```
    Dim list As New SortedList(Of Integer, Person)

    Dim p1 As Person = New Person(1, "Ian")
    Dim p2 As Person = New Person(2, "Steven")
    Dim p3 As Person = New Person(3, "Sharon")
    list.Add(p3.IDNumber, p3)
    list.Add(p1.IDNumber, p1)
    list.Add(p2.IDNumber, p2)

    For Each p As Person In list.Values
        MsgBox(p.IDNumber)
    Next
```

I have intentionally scrambled the order in which items are added to the list. Whenever the list changes, it runs a sorting algorithm to ensure that items remain in the right order. Depending on how you plan to use it, this might add quite a bit of overhead.