# Data Access Layer - Returning type that contains two entities

Tags: vb.net

Please have a look at the code in the question I asked here:  [Data Access Layer returns DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467167/data-access-layer-returns-datatable).

I have data transfer objects to represent persistent entities.  For example, say I have a table in the database called Customer and a table called Order:

CREATE TABLE Customer (ID int, Name VARCHAR(100), Primary Key (ID))
CREATE TABLE Order (ID int, Name VARCHAR(100), Primary Key (ID))

Say I wanted to retrieve all the Orders linked to a customer from the database.  I can see two options:

1) Have a type that combines Customers and Orders as follows (notice the Order array):

```
Public Class CustomerOrder
    Private _CustomerID As Integer
    Private _Name As String
    Private _OrderID() As Integer

    Public Property CustomerID() As Integer
        Get
            Return _CustomerID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _CustomerID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Name() As Integer
        Get
            Return _Name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _Name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property OrderID() As Integer()
        Get
            Return _OrderID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer())
            _OrderID = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

2) Return one customer object and a list of order objects. Customer and Order would be there own types.

I believe that option 1 is better, but I am wandering if types should target one database table only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a question of taste, and what **design pattern** you want to use. I have used both options in my projects. I could suggest that you create your `Orders` property as a `generic list` (or `IEnumerable`) of `Order` objects, do not initialize it (null), and make it readonly, so that if you don't have to use it you don't waste memory and processing time in something you won't use. And then when it is being accessed you can simply fill it in right there.

```
Private _OrderID As Integer()
Public ReadOnly Property OrderID() As Integer()
    Get
        If (_OrderID Is Nothing Or _OrderID.Length = 0) Then
            GetOrders(_CustomerID)
        End If
        Return _OrderID
    End Get
End Property
```

Again, I believe in this specific scenario whatever works best for you would be the best option. If you just need the ID's, use your array of integers, if you will need access to the other properties of the orders, use an array, object, linq, or whatever fits you better.

Comment: Thanks.  Would your point of view change if there was a one to one relationship between customer and order? i.e. orderid in the class would be an integer instead of an integer array.  +1.

Comment: I think it depends on how much I would access either objects. If I find myself using both, I would probably create just one class with the properties of both the order and the customer. All of my stored procedures and views would bring all of the data. If you look at EntityFramework and the way it would do this, it creates a list of Orders for your Customer class.

Comment: Do you mean a class called CustomerOrder containing properties for all of the fields in the Customer table and all the fields in the Order table?

Comment: Yes, of course that is in the case of a one to one relationship.

Comment: Thanks.  Last question.  Would you ever return individual database fields from the data access layer e.g. id or would you always use data transfer objects?

Comment: I've used single fields from the database numerous times: ex.: A week ago I needed a Count to implement a Pagination control. Some people would argue to avoid trips to the server for simple things like that, but I would say that instead of wasting bandwith with an entire object for just one simple ID or a count, I'd rather do a simple ajax call and obtain that ID or count from the server. Of course, a good design would go to the server as little as possible.

Comment: That is a good point.  What is the "recommended" way of retrieving scalar values e.g. counts from the database? data transfer objects?

Comment: DTOs? Rarely use them. Probably something like this: dim result As Object = myCommand.ExecuteScalar()
Dim id As Nullable(Of Integer) = Nullable(Of Integer)(!Convert.IsDBNull(result) ? result : null)

Comment: This whole question is about DTO's?

Comment: Well, yeah I guess it depends what you mean by DTO. With so much async internet programming, I just transfer JSon objects from the server to the client. But yeah I know what you mean.

Comment: Thanks.  I have asked another question on a similar topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559379/interfaces-and-hungarian-notation.  Please take a look if you have time.