# Interfaces and hungarian notation

Tags: vb.net, design-patterns

Please have a look at the following question: [What's the naming convention for classes in the DataAccess Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955875/whats-the-naming-convention-for-classes-in-the-dataaccess-project)

JDK talks about using Namespaces to separate the Data Logic Layer and the Business Logic Layer and not to use Hungarian notation to name interfaces e.g. IPersonDAL for the data access layer.  I have followed the recommendations of this answerer in the code below:

```
Imports com.app.BusinessLogicLayer.Interfaces
Imports com.app.DataLogicLayer.Interfaces
Namespace BusinessLogicLayer

        Public Class Order
            Implements com.app.BusinessLogicLayer.Interfaces.IOrder
            Public Sub Insert()
                Dim IOrder As com.app.DataLogicLayer.Interfaces.IOrder = New com.app.DataLogicLayer.Order
            End Sub
        End Class
    End Namespace

    Namespace DataLogicLayer
        Public Class Order
            Public Sub Insert()

            End Sub
        End Class
    End Namespace

    Namespace BusinessLogicLayer.Interfaces
        Public Interface IOrder

        End Interface
    End Namespace

    Namespace DataLogicLayer.Interfaces
        Public Interface IOrder

        End Interface
    End Namespace
```

Classes in the business logic layer e.g. Order implement interfaces (IOrder from Business Logic Layer) and use interfaces (IOrder from Data Logic Layer) i.e. the presentation layer communicates with the Business Logic Layer and the Business Logic Layer communicates with the data logic layer with interfaces.  Notice that because of this reason; interfaces have to be fully qualified with the namespace.  For this reason; isn't it better to name interfaces using hungarian notation e.g. IPersonBLL and IPersonDAL or am I missing something?

Comment: I would not keep BLL and DAL in class or interface names, cause it should be easy to read.

Comment: possibly relevant http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is a subjective topic, but here goes...

Firstly, avoid abbreviations like DAL.  Code Analysis yells about acronyms and abbreviations; you're supposed to write it out.  In my experience it's wise advise.  Opening up ancient code that's full of abbreviations causes a lot of unnecessary WTF moments (pun intended).

Even when spelling things out, when you have 50 classes sitting in your BusinessLogic folder like this:

`Company.Product.BusinessLogic`
  Person**Entity**
  Order**Entity**
  Material**Entity**
  Employee**Entity**
  Customer**Entity**
  etc.

My gut tells me it's time to refactor. I feel it's better to move the **Entity** tag to the namespace, so you have this:

`Company.Product.BusinessLogic.Entity`
  Person
  Order
  Material
  Employee
  Customer
  etc.

Same things applies to interfaces.

This also makes it easier to refactor. If I want to start calling my Entities "BusinessObjects", I just have to rename the namespace, not the class names and file names.

It can be a pain to qualify your class names, but you normally only have to specify the parent namespace, not fully-qualify them. Resharper -> Cleanup Code does wonders here.

In summary, I would not add Hungarian notation to my interface/class name just to make references easier to deal with.

---

### Update: Example

**Data Access Layer**:

```
Namespace Company.Product.DataAccess.Adapter
    Public Class Product
    End Class
End Namespace
```

**Business Layer**:

```
Imports Company.Product.DataAccess

Namespace Company.Product.BusinessLogic.Entity
    Public Class Product
        Dim adapter As New Adapter.Product()
    End Class
End Namespace
```

**User Interface** (ideally your UI should only interact with the business layer, never with the data layer directly):

```
Imports Company.Product.BusinessLogic

Namespace Company.Product.UserInterface.Webpage
    Public Class Product
        Dim productEntity As New Entity.Product()
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: This means that you have to use fully qualified namespaces to distinguish between interfaces in the business logic layer and interfaces in the data logic layer (as I stated in the questions).  Do you agree? I agree that it is a clean way.  +1.

Comment: You have to qualify them, but the use of "Imports" makes it so you only have to qualify the next level up.  I'll put an example in my answer

Answer (score 1):

> Notice that because of this reason; interfaces have to be fully qualified with the namespace. For this reason; isn't it better to name interfaces using hungarian notation e.g. IPersonBLL and IPersonDAL or am I missing something?

I see what you are saying, but I don't understand why fully-qualifying the names is bad or why it would be "better" to name the interfaces using "Hungarian" notation. (And I say this as a truly unrepentant fan of Simonyi's apps Hungarian.)

Remember that regardless of the names and locations of the classes/interfaces, the compiler is going to produce the same object code. The apparent nesting level is not going to "slow down" your code to any perceptible degree.

If it *really* bothers you to type out the names (and Intellisense is of no consolation), you can always use something like a [namespace alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s.aspx) with a using directive. But I'd be careful with overusing these—I think it makes the code even harder to read.

Comment: +1 for the comment: "I don't understand why fully-qualifying the names is bad or why it would be "better" to name the interfaces using "Hungarian" notation".